# How to invert the regular expression group capture logic?

Tags: regex

To create a capturing group in a regex you use `(match)` and you prefix it with `?:` to make it non-capturing, like `(?:match)`.  The thing is, in any kind of complicated regular expression I find myself wanting to create far more non-capturing groups than capturing ones, so I'd like to reverse this logic and only capture groups beginning with `?:` (or whatever).  How can I do this?  I mainly use regular expressions with .NET, but I wouldn't mind answers for other languages with regular expressions like Perl, PHP, Python, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: You could perhaps instantiate your RegEx object with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @elgonzo That looks good, if you put it as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the clumsiness of `(?: )` and turn `( )` groups into non-capturing groups, use the [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options?view=netframework-4.7.2#explicit-captures-only) option. Only named groups (`(?<name>subexpression)`) will be captured if this option is being used.

However, you cannot turn non-capturing groups `(?: )` into capturing groups, unfortunately.

The RegEx constructor as well as other methods from the RegEx class accept `RegexOptions` flags.

For example:

```
Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
```

Answer (score 3):

In any language that supports [named capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) you can simply use them for what you want captured, and ignore the numbered ones.

```
my $string = q(Available from v5.10 in Perl.);

$string =~ /([A-Z].+?)(?<ver>[0-9.]+)\s+(.*?)\./;

say "Version: $+{ver}";
```

After the regex the capture is in `%+` hash, while inside the regex it's `\k<name>` or `\g{name}`.

The downside is that you still capture all that other stuff (what hurts efficiency a little), while the upside is that you still capture all that other stuff (what helps flexibility, if some turns out needed).